# In IntelliJ IDEA, why is the Subversion integration not working for me (all Subversion-related commands are always disabled)?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I configured IntelliJ IDEA 6.0.6 to use Subversion for version control. The Subversion menu item now appears in the context menu when I right click a Java file within the project. However, all the sub menu items are disabled:

- Subversion > Add
- Subversion > Check
- Subversion > Edit Properties

(..)

- Subversion > Unlock

The exceptions are Subversion > Revert, Subversion > Annotate and Subversion > Browse Changes, which are enabled. However, if I try Annotate, for example, I get this error:

> Error: svn: C:...\tools
>   is not a working copysvn: Cannot read
>   from to C:...\tools.svn\format: path
>   refers to directory or read access is
>   denied.

When I use my Subversion client outside of the IDE (which is Tortoise SVN), everything works fine.

Does anybody know the solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have a newer version of the Subversion client than that which is included in IDEA. For instance, if you are using Subversion 1.6 from outside IDEA, than the Subversion library in IDEA 6.0.6 (I don't remember which version this was, but probably Subversion 1.3 or 1.4) won't be able to read your working copy.

The only solution to this, AFAIK, is to make sure only to access any given working copy, either through one Subversion client, or at least using the same version Subversion libraries in each client that accesses the working copy.

Comment: Thanks. The solution for this was to re-check out the project from IntelliJ, so that it used the subversion client version that it knows how to handle.